# Java: Implicitly casting Object to child types - "good" or "bad"?

Tags: java, casting

### I have something like this:

ObjTester.java

```
class ObjTester{
    private static Object obj;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        obj = (Integer)1;
        System.out.println("obj.getClass(): " + obj.getClass());
        obj = 1;
        System.out.println("obj.getClass(): " + obj.getClass());
    }
}
```

### The output is:

obj.getClass(): class java.lang.Integer
obj.getClass(): class java.lang.Integer

Does this mean that I don't have to do explicit type casting? In both case, obj is converted into Integer. Is this kind of practice "good"/advisable? Would it generate any problem?

Comment: If you want a `Byte` object, that would be one valid way to do it. Without the cast, you'd be getting an `Integer`.

Comment: Sorry. My question was not specific enough. I'm amending it now.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for reference! Yet I still want to know if this "good" or "bad" - would it generate any problem?

Comment: You're assigning to a variable of type `Object`. A cast will always* be unnecessary in that case. * Except for what @thilo just mentioned.

Comment: Many thanks! You're a real savior of a java beginner!